# Displaying from 3 tables, one uses join and the other does not

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I got 3 tables: transaction, member and mtrans. I want to get all rows from transaction. I also wanted to get the rows from member and mtrans where member.id = mtrans.mid

The problem is, I don't know how to send the data I get. This is my code:

Controller

```
    function profile(){
    $data["info"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData1();
    $data["info"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData2();

    $data["page"] = "profile";

    $this->load->view("include/template.php", $data);
}
```

Model

```
    function getData1(){
    $this->db->from("transaction");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['info'] = $query->result_array();

    return $data;
}

function getData2(){
    $this->db->from("member as m");
    $this->db->join("mtrans as mt", "mt.mid = m.id");
    $this->db->where("m.id", $this->uri->segment(3));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['info'] = $query->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

So, am I doing it right? How do I display in view?

At least post how check the data collected using print_r.

Comment: In your view they will be stored as the variable $info but right now they will only show getData2 so you may want to create $data['info1'] and $data['info2'] and store the separate data into two different variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is only for helping you to print the data in your view using print_r.

In your controller, you are overwriting the data you got from the function getData1() with the data you got from getData2();

```
function profile(){
$data["info"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData1();
//data stored in $data["info"]
$data["info"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData2();
//data stored in $data["info"] overwritten
$data["page"] = "profile";
$this->load->view("include/template.php", $data);
}
```

I would suggest you store them in two different array keys..

```
$data["info1"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData1();
$data["info2"] = $this->itransaction_model->getData2();
```

Then in your view you can use

```
print_r($info1);
print_r($info2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your model `getData1()`

```
$this->db->select("t.*,m.*");
$this->db->from("mtrans as mt");
$this->db->join("member as m","mt.mid = m.id");
$this->db->join("transaction as t","mt.tid = t.id");
$this->db->where("m.id", $this->uri->segment(3));
$query = $this->db->get();
$res = $query->result_array();
print_r($res);
```